# What is the most logical walkthrough to successfully run an automated test using Microsoft Test Manager (MTM) 2010?

Tags: automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager, regression-testing

I am new in testing, and to be honest I would like to start over because I have been reading a lots of articles in msdn library, now I am confused...Please help!

What I have done:

- I created an automated coded UI test (CUIT) in VS 2010
- The CUIT is taking data from an Excel File
- Created a link between the excel file and CUIT folowing this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/03/17/data-driving-coded-ui-tests.aspx)

My MS Tools

- Microsoft Test Manager 2010
- Visual Studio 2010
- Team Foundation Server 2010 & Team Foundation Build
- SQL Server 2008 R2 (if relevant)

**Objective**: Use my PC to run an automated test in a **physical enviroment** without extra tools

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `CodedUi Tests` through MTM is the same procedure as any other automated test. You have to do the following:

1. [Associate your CodedUi Test with appropriate Test Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
2. In the physical machine you use for automated tests install a Test Controller and a Test Agent. [Configure the Test Agent to interact with the desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee291332%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
3. [Create a Test Plan in MTM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286583%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [add your Test Cases to the appropriate Test Suites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286719%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#CreateSuite).
4. [Select the Test Environment you want to run your tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465179%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Select the physical machine you had previously install and configure the Test Controller and Agent.
5. Run your tests and happy testing

For more details follow these guides:

- [How to: Run Automated Tests from a Test Plan Using Microsoft Test Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553270%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Running Automated Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286580%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you this book [Software Testing with Visual Studio 2010](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167335/Software-Testing-with-Visual-Studio-2010).

It will provide you with an excellent walkthrough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a Test Controller service and Test Agent on the environments you want to run the tests on.

This will allow you to execute the tests remotely without having visual studio installed.

see these links for more info

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd648127(v=vs.100).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728093(v=vs.100).aspx

alternatively you can call the mstest.exe directly and pass in a parameter for the test project, but i'm not sure what installs this. Probably visual studio and the agents

Once setup the agents can be managed via the Lab in MTM